# Wifi disconnects? randomly

Tags: networking, wireless

Every once in a while, my wifi symbol turns into a question mark, and I can't open new webpages, but existing connections seem to remain open. If I am on a Discord call, the call will continue to work despite not being able to connect to webpages or start a new call. Streaming video will continue to play (though eventually it will stop working, I imagine it needs to reset the connection every so often). I need to turn wifi off and on again in order to make a new connection.

This seems to be very inconsistent. It won't happen at all for several days and then for no apparent reason it will start happening every 30 minutes or so. Sometimes it will happen once and then disappear again for a while.

This started happening a few months ago when I flew home for the summer, so I assumed it was network specific, but it is happening with other networks too. I don't know what changed to cause this to start happening.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Please do share some solution if and when you find one. You can also follow my question which might be helpful if it gets answered first.  https://askubuntu.com/q/1329884/1022606